# Rails shows "active_admin is not yet checked out." error in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to deploy Rails app in Digital Ocean. Right now unicorn's logs shows this line:

```
ERROR -- : git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git (at master) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first. (Bundler::GitError)
```

This is the part of Gemfile that uses 'active_admin' gem:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

I'm using Rails 4.1.0 and Ruby 2.1.2p95. Does anyone know what is this error about and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bundle install --no-deployment
```